# Message file UTILITY_MEG\spw<lang>.msb not found

Tags: oracle, cmd, oracle11g, sqlplus, database-administration

**I want to open SQL*Plus from CMD**

When I try to open it using this command in `Sqlplus` I encounter this dialog error message:

`Message file UTILITY_MEG\spw<lang>.msb not found`.

after I close dialog message here is a copy of CMD:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Abo-Khaled>sqlplus
Error 14 initializing SQL*Plus
Message file sp1<lang>.msb not found
SP2-0750: You may need to set ORACLE_HOME to your Oracle software directory

C:\Users\Abo-Khaled>
```

I used these commands to solve the problem:

```
set oracle_home=C:\app\Abo-Khaled\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\

set oracle_sid=orcl
```

**BUT** that doesn't solve the problem.

**Notes:**

- When I use SQL*Plus directly I can login without any problem. but I need to login using CMD.
- I am using `oracle 11g` in windows 7
- About one month ago I hadn't this problem with SQL*Plus.

Comment: Probably you have changed some windows language setting that means SQLPlus is looking for a language file that is not installed. Check for .msb files in the \sqlplus\mesg\ subfolder of your oracle home.

Comment: there is  3 files in C:\app\Abo-Khaled\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\sqlplus\mesg.

: cpyus.msb , sp1us.msb and sp2us.msb @AndrewBrennan

Comment: set the NLS_LANG parameter to an appropriate value

Comment: I tried this command : set nls_language='ENGLISH' but that wasn't helpful.

Comment: Sorry, you need to set the full value: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue and was able to resolve it by adjusting my windows path environment variable.

Make sure the path to the bin directory containing the correct sqlplus.exe comes first in the Windows path environment variable.

When you use sqlplus.exe in a command prompt, you may be executing a different sqlplus.exe than intended.

In my case, I also have the Oracle middleware installed which has its own sqlplus.exe which was being referenced and throwing the "Message file" error.

Once I put the path to the database home's bin directory first in the path variable, the issue went away.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the NLS_LANG parameter in your command prompt. e.g. set nls_lang=ENGLISH

Answer (score 0):

For the newer database 12c and up, I did not need an oracle_home variable. If you have one, then try deleting to see if the "Message file sp1.msb not found" goes away. This has been my experience of installing an Oracle DB on a desktop/laptop.